# Spring mvc JSR 303 hibernate validator not working with custom validator

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

Custom validator excludes hibernate.validator in spring mvc.

```
@RestController
public void foo(@Valid Bar bar){

}
```

now annotating class like this :

```
@FooAnnotation
public class Bar{

   @NotNull
   private String name;

   private List<Foo> foos;

   public List<Foo> getFoos(){
      return foos;
   }
}
```

And finally validator

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy =FooConstraint.class)
public @interface FooAnnotation{

String message() default "";
Class<?>[] groups() default {};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

So using regular spring-boot this setup works just fine. Having to re-work one legacy rest-api and not being able to upgrade to latest version of spring or hibernate validator i am kinda stuck.

removing `@FooAnnotation` everything works fine `@NotNull` works as expected, but with `@FooAnnotation` my custom validation logic is working but `@NotNull` is not.
Ideas?

EDIT  :
EDIT2 : added validation logic
EDIT3 : versions

```
public class FooConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<FooAnnotation,Bar> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(FooAnnotation ff) {

    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Bar resource, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {

      return (resource.getFoos().size()<30);
    }
}
```

hibernate-validator - 4.3.1.Final
spring-webmvc - 4.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Please add the actual validator, you only provided the annotation.

Comment: As mentioned please add the validation.. You haven't added anything that we wouldn't already know.

Comment: sorry to start up this old thread. but were you able to find a solution to this issue? I am facing similar issue and have searched all over internet and hibernate-validator docs but did not find any answer to this problem.